# urw-fonts making X11 worse? PDF alternatives

Tags: centos, x11, fonts

I have an in-house app that we're using across an X11 connection.  The app looks great on a minimal install of X11. However, the machine also requires a PDF reader, most of which require `urw-fonts` to be installed. Once `urw-fonts` is installed, the main application is changed (presumably to use one of the PS fonts in `urw-fonts`) and looks awful. I want to preserve the original font for the application, but also have a PDF reader. I'm exploring 'Zathura' with PDF support as an option (it doesn't seem to require `urw-fonts`), but I'm open to a smarter way to do this.  Is there a way to limit `urw-fonts` to only the PDF reader, say `evince`? Or some other approach? Remove `urw-fonts` in system control somehow?

Comment: Can't you configure the in-house app to use whatever fonts it is using on the minimal install instead of `urw-fonts`? You didn't tell us anything about the in-house app, but all X apps I've used so far allow you to configure fonts. If it was written with one of the standard toolkits that options comes automatically. Much easier to do it this way than to fiddle around with the PDF reader.

Comment: @dirkt I (incorrectly) refer to it as an "in house" app because it's a custom application (vice open source) that I do not really have any insight into (I'm just trying to get the OS built to support it). I have been in contact with the developers, but in the event they don't have an answer I'm wondering if there's a system level change I can make to isolate `urw-fonts` from that application.